# the binary expression cannot be converted to a predicate expression in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, llblgenpro

I want to get the week number of a certain given `DateTime`.

```
public static int WeekOf(DateTime? date)
            {
                if (date.HasValue)
                {
                    GregorianCalendar gCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
                    int WeekNumber = gCalendar.GetWeekOfYear(date.Value, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
                    return WeekNumber;
                }
                else
                    return 0;
            }
```

And then I use the above method in:

```
public static List<ExpressionListDictionary> MyMethod(int weeknr)
        {
            using (DataAccessAdapter adapter = CreateAdapter())
            {
                LinqMetaData meta = new LinqMetaData(adapter);
                var q = (from i in meta.Test
                         where WeekOf(i.StartDate) == weeknr
                         select new ExpressionListDictionary()
                             {                                 
                                {"SomeId", i.Id}
                             }
                );
                return q.ToList();
            }
        }
```

And finally:

```
    List<ExpressionListDictionary> someIDs =  MyMethod(weeknr);
/* weeknr = 19 -> step by step debugging */
```

**Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.ORMQueryConstructionException: The binary expression '(WeekOf(Convert(EntityField(LPLA_1.StartDate AS StartDate))) == 19)' can't be converted to a predicate expression.

I do get the title error at return q.ToList(); . How can I achieve this?

Comment: From the name of the classes, are you using the *llblgen* library?

Comment: Yes, I do use in my project the llblgen library

Comment: maybe adding brackets will help in this case. Like: where (WeekOf(i.StartDate) == weeknr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't ever used the LLBLGen library/framework... But probably this is the same problem that happens with Entity Framework/LINQ-to-SQL: you can't put in a query C# methods: the query must be executed by your db server, not locally, and your db server doesn't know how to execute C# code. So the problem would be in the 
`**WeekOf(i.StartDate)** == weeknr` part of code (that is the only `BinaryExpression` of your query)

The exception you have posted is quite clear that the point of the error is the one that I have suggested. Then the reason is probably the one I gave you.

Taken from https://www.llblgen.com/tinyforum/Messages.aspx?ThreadID=22861

If you are using SQL Server, that supports `DATEPART(isowk, ...)` (or if you have MySQL, that supports `WEEK(...)`)

```
public class SQLFunctionMappings : FunctionMappingStore
{
    public SQLFunctionMappings()
    {
        Add(new FunctionMapping(
            typeof(SQLFunctions),
            "WeekOf",
            1,
            "DATEPART(isowk, {0})") // For SQL Server
            // "WEEK({0}, 1)") For MySQL
        );
    }
}

public class SQLFunctions
{
    public static int? WeekOf(DateTime? date)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then you would use it like:

Where there is the row with `LinqMetaData meta = new LinqMetaData(adapter)`, add:

```
meta.CustomFunctionMappings = new SQLFunctionMappings();
```

and change the `where`:

```
where SQLFunctions.WeekOf(i.StartDate) == weeknr
```

[Here](https://www.llblgen.com/documentation/2.6/Using%20the%20generated%20code/Linq/gencode_linq_functionmappings.htm) there is the list of the functions already mapped by llblgen, and how to map other functions.

Comment: xanatos, yep I also think the problem is there ... And, now, I'm going back to my initial problem: how to get using LINQ, the week number of a certain given datetime?

Comment: Could I use: SqlFunctions.DatePart ? But I can't even resolve this method, adding some certain namespace...

Comment: @FlorinM. If you need other SQL functions, you can easily adapt that code to the other SQL functions. The `1,` is the number of parameters that will be passed (so if you want to have two parameters in the function, you put `2`)

Comment: Thanks for your great tips and informations. I really hope this question/answer will help many others

Comment: If I want the week to begin from sunday ( not monday ) how to modify it ?

Comment: @FlorinM. Don't know... Best thing is that you ask a new question on how to do it in the SQL dialect that you are using, and then adapt the response to the `SQLFunctionMappings` (that is quite generic)

Comment: @FlorinM. For MySQL it is easy: use `"WEEK({0}, 4)"`. For SQL Server I don't know

Answer (score 0):

you can try to Make the method you have WeekOf takes `string` instead of `Datetime?`

```
public static int WeekOf(String dateAsString)
            {
               //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateAsString))
                if (!dateAsString.equals(string.empty))
                {
                    GregorianCalendar gCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
                    int WeekNumber = gCalendar.GetWeekOfYear(date.Value,  CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
                    return WeekNumber;
                }
                else
                    return 0;
            }
```

And then you use the above below in:

```
public static List<ExpressionListDictionary> MyMethod(int weeknr)
        {
            using (DataAccessAdapter adapter = CreateAdapter())
            {
                LinqMetaData meta = new LinqMetaData(adapter);
                var q = (from i in meta.Test
                         where i.startDate != null && WeekOf(i.StartDate.tostring()) == weeknr
                         select new ExpressionListDictionary()
                             {                                 
                                {"SomeId", i.Id}
                             }
                );
                return q.ToList();
            }
        }
```

Comment: i afraid i don't understand, no need to change the weeknr to string as you are comparing weeknr(int) with weekof( function return int).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyMethod(5);
        }
        public static int WeekOf(DateTime? date)
        {
            if (date.HasValue)
            {
                GregorianCalendar gCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
                int WeekNumber = gCalendar.GetWeekOfYear(date.Value, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
                return WeekNumber;
            }
            else
                return 0;
        }
        public static List<ExpressionListDictionary> MyMethod(int weeknr)
        {
            using (DataAccessAdapter adapter = CreateAdapter())
            {
                LinqMetaData meta = new LinqMetaData(adapter);
                List<ExpressionListDictionary> q = (from i in meta.Test
                         where WeekOf(i.StartDate) == weeknr
                         select new ExpressionListDictionary()
                         {
                                Id = "SomeId"
                         }
                ).ToList();
                return q;
            }
        }
        public static DataAccessAdapter CreateAdapter()
        {
            return new DataAccessAdapter();
        }
    }
    public class ExpressionListDictionary
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
    public class LinqMetaData
    {
        public List<LinqMetaData> Test {get;set;}
        public DateTime StartDate {get;set;}
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public LinqMetaData(DataAccessAdapter adapter)
        {
        }
    }
    public class DataAccessAdapter : IDisposable
    {

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }


}
​
```